# Difference of two complex numbers is positive and an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Suppose that $\alpha_n,\beta_n\in\mathbb{C}$ and $p_n>0$, and we have that
$$
\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n-\alpha_n\beta_{n-1}=\frac{1}{p_{n-1}}.\qquad (*)
$$
Since right-hand side is positive, the left-hand side must be positive as well. Can I then say that it implies that $\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n>\alpha_n\beta_{n-1}$? If not, please explain why, when the expression in (*) is positive.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n$ and $\alpha_n\beta_{n-1}$ can both be complex. So it is incorrect to say $\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n > \alpha_n\beta_{n-1}$.

$|\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n| > |\alpha_n\beta_{n-1}|$ is also not correct. For example $(-1 + i) - (-2 + i) = 1$ but $|-1 + i| = \sqrt{2} < \sqrt{5} = |-2+i|$.

Comment: To your first line, we can't say this inequality holds, even though the difference is positive? Would it be then correct to say that $1/b_n\leq |\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n|+|\alpha_n\beta_{n-1}|$, so we get $- |\alpha_{n-1}\beta_n|< |\alpha_n\beta_{n-1}|$?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "we can't say". If you want you can define a partial order on $\mathbb{C}$ by $z\geq w$ if $z-w\in\mathbb{R_+}$. But it's not a very common definition. Most of the time we are not comparing complex numbers.

Comment: It depends on how you define "$>$". Unlike $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field and is usually not associated with comparison operations. You could of course define your own operator but even then, that equation might not hold.